# Error using knnMatch with OpenCV+Python

Tags: python, opencv, runtime-error

I want to match two pictures using Python+OpenCV. I have used SURF to extract keypoints and descriptors from both of them. Now, I need to match these descriptors and for this reason I decided to use Flann Matcher.

```
flann_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE,trees = 4)    
matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(flann_params, {})
```

But when I try to use knnMatch with descriptors (desc1, desc2), openCV throws an exception.

```
raw_matches=matcher.knnMatch(np.asarray(desc1),np.asarray(desc2), 2)
```

The exception is the following:

```
raw_matches=matcher.knnMatch(np.asarray(desc1),np.asarray(desc2), 2) #2
cv2.error: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp:299: error: (-210) type=6
 in function buildIndex_
```

How I could use knnMatch correctly? Is it a Bug?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I solved this problem using the correct data type with the function np.asarray()

```
raw_matches=matcher.knnMatch(np.asarray(desc1,np.float32),np.asarray(desc2,np.float32), 2) #2
```

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301962/opencv-pythons-api-flannbasedmatcher).

Here is the relevant code, from [Esteban Angee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053925/esteban-angee)'s answer:

```
r_threshold = 0.6
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1  # bug: flann enums are missing
```

Construct your parameters dictionary:

```
flann_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 4)
flann = cv2.flann_Index(desc2, flann_params)
```

Perform nearest neighbours search:

```
idx2, dist = flann.knnSearch(desc1, 2, params = {}) # bug: need to provide empty dict
mask = dist[:,0] / dist[:,1] < r_threshold
idx1 = np.arange(len(desc1))
pairs = np.int32( zip(idx1, idx2[:,0]) )
```

Returns the descriptors that matched:

```
return pairs[mask]
```

I am not at my workstation right now, so I'm afraid I can't look at what's wrong with your code, but the above question solved all my troubles when I had the same problem.  You do not have to use `FlannBasedMatcher`, I remember that I also had problems with it.

If it does not help, I will see if I can find my solution tomorrow or so.

Comment: I have the same mistake but in this case using     idx2=cv2.flann_Index()idx2.build(np.asarray(desc2),flann_params)
cv2.error: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp:299: error: (-210) type=6
 in function buildIndex_

Comment: Did you try the code I posted in my answer?  It worked for me.  I'm afraid I don't really understand your comment?

Comment: Yes I'm using OpenCV-2.4.2. When I tried your code cv2.flann_Index(desc2, flann_params) throwed an exception about no module. I read that you need to code the following functions: idx2=cv2.flann_Index()idx2.build(np.asarray(desc2),flann_params)

Comment: Maybe you are working with a different setup, I did not need to code any additional functions.  My setup is Python 2.7 with OpenCV 2.4 on Windows 7.

Comment: I have Mac OS. I followed these steps to install opencv with python. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6087778/577909