# OpenCV and Python: Problems with knnMatch arguments

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to follow the opencv tutorial [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html#matcher). Unfortunately, it fails at flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2). Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np

im1 = cv2.imread('61_a.tif')
im2 = cv2.imread('61_b.tif')

surf = cv2.SURF(500,3,4,1,0) 
print "Detect and Compute"
kp1 = surf.detect(im1,None)
kp2 = surf.detect(im2,None)

des1 = surf.compute(im1,kp1)
des2 = surf.compute(im2,kp2)

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 5
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks = 50)

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
```

I get the error:

```
matches = matcher.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
TypeError: Argument given by name ('k') and position (2)
```

I have tried to change the matching to mirror the [fix in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508934/error-using-knnmatch-with-opencvpython) like so:

```
flann = cv2.flann_Index(des2, index_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,2,params={})
```

BUT then I get this error:

```
flann = cv2.flann_Index(des2, index_params)
TypeError: features is not a numerical tuple
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

If you happen to know of a working PYTHON example of SURF or ORB for panorama/stitching that's fairly straightforward, I would appreciate that too. I have googled around quite a bit and have only found pieces of operations about how it might be accomplished (or it's written in C) or have only found unfinished/broken examples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`surf.compute()` returns both keypoints and descriptors lists. `flann.knnMatch()` gets confused because `des1` is a pair of lists and instead of `k=1` it finds another pair of lists (namely `des2`). Check the `shape()` of des1 and des2.

Either pass `des1[1]` and `des2[1]` to `flann.knnMatch()` or use `surf.detectAndCompute()` in replacement of `surf.detect()` and `surf.compute()`.